# docker: invalid reference format - Installing nginx proxy

Tags: docker, powershell, nginx

I'm getting this error when trying to run this on a Windows machine through PowerShell. Any ideas what's causing the error?

`docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --restart always --name nginx-proxy -v "//var/run/docker.sock":/tmp/docker.sock:ro danielpanzella/nginx-proxy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `""` is the root cause, looks `""` just works for linux, for windows, you have to remove `""` as next:

```
PS C:\> docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --restart always --name nginx-proxy -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro danielpanzella/nginx-proxy
02ac60b503011a2dec0692157ad4e9f3003f444986f8a75370a8f8b1beac9b8f
PS C:\> docker logs nginx-proxy
WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
Generating a RSA private key
.....+++++
..........................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to '/etc/nginx/certs/dev.key'
-----
Generating a RSA private key
................................................................................+++++
.....+++++
writing new private key to '/etc/nginx/certs/test.key'
-----
Generating a RSA private key
..............................+++++
................................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to '/etc/nginx/certs/local.key'
-----
Generating a RSA private key
................+++++
......................................+++++
writing new private key to '/etc/nginx/certs/nip.io.key'
-----
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2021/06/11 04:57:53 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 1 containers
dockergen.1 | 2021/06/11 04:57:53 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2021/06/11 04:57:53 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2021/06/11 04:57:53 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
2021/06/11 04:58:37 [notice] 57#57: signal process started
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
dhparam generation complete, reloading nginx
```

Comment: Dude, that worked perfect! You are the man!